# Data length validation in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have 4 tables called A, B, C, D. These 4 tables have 10,20,30,40 columns. But these 4 tables are have 5 common columns with the same datatype and different lengths.

My action to be done is, I send a table of values (single row which has the values of those 5 common values also) to stored procedure.

Now I want to insert the row into a table which should be found by the table name (table name is available in the row itself). And there before I need to do data length validation.

It should not be like

```
if(len(@value1) > 800)
```

I need some different way to produce the length validation. Because in future, I may change the length of the column for some purpose. At the time I cannot change the value in the stored procedure. Please give me the solution

Comment: which dbms ? sqlserver ?

Comment: Yes. MS Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`  view to fetch information of the column belonging to the table .

```
DECLARE @ColumnLength INT

SELECT @ColumnLength  = CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND COLUMN_NAME='columnName'

-- Use the variable @ColumnLength for conditons in your stored proc so need of hardcoding length

IF LEN(@value1) > @ColumnLength 
BEGIN

 -- Your statements
END
```

Comment: It is best way to solve the validation if there is minimum no. of columns validation. But when I go with more than 10 columns, it is taking too much time to validate and it may cause to timeout error.

Comment: It is best way to solve the validation if there is minimum no. of columns validation. But when I go with more than 10 columns, it is taking too much time to validate and it may cause to timeout error. 

Could you please the suggest any other simple way?

Comment: Thanks hasan. Could any one please suggest?